# Issue setting up Git-Sync with Airflow in a Pod

Tags: git, kubernetes, airflow

I am currently trying to setup Airflow to work in a Kubernetes like environment. For airflow to be useful, I need to be able to use the Git-Sync features so that the DAGs can be stored seperatly from the Pod, thus not being reset when the Pod downscales or restarts. I am trying to set it up with ssh.

I have been searching for good documentation on the Airflow config or tutorials on how to set this up properly, but this has been to no avail. I would very much appreciate some help here, as I have been struggling with this for a while.

Here is how i set the relevant config, please note I have some stand ins for links and some information due to security reasons:

```
git_repo = https://<git-host>/scm/<project-name>/airflow
git_branch = develop
git_subpath = dags
git_sync_root = /usr/local/airflow
git_sync_dest = dags
git_sync_depth = 1
git_sync_ssh = true
git_dags_folder_mount_point = /usr/local/airflow/dags
git_ssh_key_secret_name = airflow-secrets
git_ssh_known_hosts_configmap_name = airflow-configmap
dags_folder = /usr/local/airflow/
executor = KubernetesExecutor
dags_in_image = False
```

Here is how I have setup my origin/config repo:

```
-root
 |-configmaps/airflow
   |-airflow.cfg
   |-airflow-configmap.yaml
 |-environment
   |-<environment specific stuff>
 |-secrets
   |-airflow-secrets.yaml
 |-ssh
   |-id_rsa
   |-id_rsa.pub
 |-README.md
```

The airflow-conifgmap and secrets look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: airflow-secrets
data:
  # key needs to be gitSshKey
  gitSshKey: <base64 encoded private sshKey>
```

and

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: airflow-configmap
data:
  known_hosts: |
      https://<git-host>/ ssh-rsa <base64 encoded public sshKey>
```

The repo that I am trying to sync to has the Public key set as an access key and is just a folder named dags with 1 dag inside.

My issue is that I do not know what my issue is at this point. I have no way of knowing what part of my config has been set correctly and what part of it is set incorrectly and documentation on the subject is very lackluster.

If there is more information that is required I will be happy to provide it.

Thank you for your time

Comment: were you able to get this to work?

Answer (score 4):

Whats the error you're seeing on doing this ?

Couple of things you need to consider:

- Create an SSH key locally using this [link](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) and:

  1. Repository Name > Settings > Deploy Keys > Value of ssh_key.pub
  2. Ensure "write access" is checked
- My `Dockerfile` I'm using looks like:

  ```
  FROM apache/airflow:2.1.2

  COPY requirements.txt .

  RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
  ```
- The `values.yaml` from the official Airflow Helm repository (`helm repo add apache-airflow https://airflow.apache.org`) needs the following values updated under `gitSync`:

  - `enabled: true`
  - `repo: ssh://git@github.com/username/repository-name.git`
  - `branch: master`
  - `subPaths: ""` (if DAGs are in repository root)
  - `sshKeySecret: airflow-ssh-git-secret`
  - `credentialsSecret: git-credentials`
- Export SSH key and `known_hosts` to Kubernetes secret for accessing the private repository

  ```
  kubectl create secret generic airflow-ssh-git-secret \
    --from-file=gitSshKey=/path/to/.ssh/id_ed25519 \
    --from-file=known_hosts=/path/to/.ssh/known_hosts \
    --from-file=id_ed25519.pub=/path/to/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub \
    -n airflow
  ```
- Create and apply manifests:

  ```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Secret
  metadata:
    namespace: airflow
    name: airflow-ssh-git-secret
  data:
    gitSshKey: <base64_encoded_private_key_id_ed25519_in_one_line>
  ```

  ```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Secret
  metadata:
    name: git-credentials
  data:
    GIT_SYNC_USERNAME: base64_encoded_git_username
    GIT_SYNC_PASSWORD: base64_encoded_git_password
  ```

  ```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: ConfigMap
  metadata:
    namespace: airflow
    name: known-hosts
  data:
    known_hosts: |
      line 1 of known_host file
      line 2 of known_host file
      line 3 of known_host file
      ...
  ```
- Update Airflow release

  `helm upgrade --install airflow apache-airflow/airflow -n airflow -f values.yaml --debug`
- Get pods in the *airflow* namespace

  `kubectl get pods -n airflow`
- The `airflow-scheduler-SOME-STRING` pod is going to have 3 containers running. View the logs of container `git-sync-init` if you dont see the pods in Running state

Comment: would you mind to give some advice on how to set up the know_hosts? Any example string would be awesome!

Comment: @Bennimi - After you complete the GitHub SSH link in my answer, you'll have to do `ssh -T git@github.com` (Password will be the same as the one you used during SSH setup). This will create an entry in the `known_hosts` file, which is located in `~/.ssh` by default. Copy the contents of that file in the `ConfigMap` manifest above. Everytime you add a remote origin SSH URL of a repository, the `known_hosts` file gets updated.

Comment: thanks much appreciated. I applied the known_hosts directly in the yml and it works too.